# Why does this service return a promise rather than a fulfilled promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, promise, angular-promise

I understand Angular promises, when Angular makes request with `$http`, the `.then(function(res){ return res })` is supposed to wait until the promise is resolved. Therefore, if I attached the request to a variable, shouldn't the variable's value be that resolved promise?

**Service to call the Github API**

```
is.service('githubApiService', function($http) {
    this.repo = function(user, repo) {
        var value = $http.get('https://api.github.com/repos/' + user + '/' + repo).then(function(json) {
            return {
                stargazers_count: json.data.stargazers_count,
                watchers_count: json.data.watchers_count,
                forks_count: json.data.forks_count, 
                watchers: json.data.watchers, 
               subscribers_count: json.data.subscribers_count
            };
        });

    return value;
    };
})
```

**Directive that calls the Service**

```
is.directive('chart', function(githubApiService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', 
        template: '<svg margin="[20, 30, 30, 40]", width="750" height="450"></svg>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var ais = githubApiService.repo('srph', 'angular-infinite-scroll');
            var ai = githubApiService.repo('thenikso','angular-inview');
            var ns = githubApiService.repo('jankuca', 'ng-scroller');

            console.log(ai); // returns a promise!
       }
   }
})
```

Comment: Nope. `then` waits *with executing the callback* until the promise is fulfilled, and *returns another promise*. It does not block your script until the asynchronous task is done!

Comment: A fulfilled promise is still a promise, so your wording is a bit odd. I suspect you mean something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the value of the promise like you are expecting.

If you look at [$q documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), you will see that the `then` method that you are chaining returns also a promise:

> *This method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using promise chaining)*

You therefore have to get the returned value through a success handler:

```
githubApiService.repo(...).then(function (data) {
    // data is the object you are expecting
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. It returns the promise in all scenarios, you need to use `.then()` to get the data you want:

```
githubApiService.repo('thenikso','angular-inview').then(function(data){
    var ai = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns the promise because you do not know when the underlying asynchronous call will be completed.

In some trivial cases this may happen almost immediately, but until you explicitly 'resolve' the fulfilled or rejected promise via the `then` method, you just have the actual promise.

Consider these two methods where `doSomething` returns a promise:

```
    myService.doSomething().then(function(data){
      return data;
    });

    myService.doSomething().then(function(data){
      //This is some non-trivial calculation that will take a few seconds to do
      var myData = transformData(data);
      return myData;
    });
```

The promise allows you to deal with both these calls the same way, where you have to resolve it with a `then` method call and not actually worry if the data is ready or not at that point in your program.